# Retrive row number of MIN IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to know the row being used in a `MIN(IF())` formula so I can use it to grab a another value in the same row..

I have this formula:

Between the two sheets
A is an Id 
B is a Date
C is another Id on Sheet2

`{=MIN(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A1,B1-Sheet2!B:B,""))}`

I want to know which row in `Sheet2!B:B` is being used to calculate the formula, then return the value in Sheet2 column C for that row.

Maybe I could use `INDEX` or `MATCH` if I only knew the row number being used in the calculation!

A different formula may have to be used to achieve this, but I wanted to demonstrate what I have so far.  It is calculating correctly.  I just need it to grab the Id in Sheet2 column C now...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's not at all a good idea to use entire column references within an array formula (or indeed any other non-CSE array-processing function, such as `SUMPRODUCT`, `AGGREGATE`, etc.).

Unlike some functions, e.g. `COUNTIF(S)`, `SUMIF(S)`, with which the use of entire column references has virtually no detriment to calculation performance, array-processing functions must calculate over **all cells** passed to them. And that applies equally to those cells which are beyond the last non-empty cell in the range being passed.

So if, for example, you only have data extending as far as row 1000, then, by using entire column references in such a formula, you are forcing Excel to calculate **more than one million** cells beyond that which is actually necessary, an astonishing amount for a single formula.

As such, it is important to either choose a suitably low - though sufficient - value for the upper row reference, or else make your ranges dynamic, such that the upper row reference is determined via a function which automatically detects the last-used cell within the column, thus offering maximum efficiency.

As to your problem, you can use the following array formula:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(MIN(IF(Sheet2!A1:A100=A1,B1-Sheet2!B1:B100)),IF(Sheet2!A1:A100=A1,B1-Sheet2!B1:B100),0))`

Note that I choose an upper row reference of 100 here, which obviously you can amend, though bearing in mind the points I raised earlier. If you like, I can also show you how to set up the dynamic ranges to which I alluded.

Also note the repetition of the conditional statement within `MATCH`'s *lookup_array*, a crucial point which is missed an astonishing number of times in proposed solutions to this kind of problem, the error being to use simply:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(MIN(IF(Sheet2!A1:A100=A1,B1-Sheet2!B1:B100)),B1-Sheet2!B1:B100,0))`

which, although it *may* work, does not at all *guarantee* correct results, by virtue of it being logically flawed.

Regards

Comment: You are a beast!  Good to know about the array, I will be sure to limit the rows in the future.  I will not need to know the dynamic ranges for this job but thank you for offering.  I will simply hard code the last row, which is fine for my purposes.  Do you mind explaining why the repeated conditional statements?  Thank you very much for the help!  I'm making a $50 donation to the National MS Society to pass on your helping spirit!

Comment: You're welcome! And a very kind gesture indeed. This article - although relating to finding the maximum rather than the minimum - contains an explanation a little way down as to why the repetition is necessary: http://excelxor.com/2015/02/22/return-entry-corresponding-to-maximum-value-based-on-conditions/. Regards.